# Universal.torrent (monotorrent) Access to the path '...' is denied

Tags: c#, path, monotorrent

I get an error "Acces to the path '...' is denied" when i try to download a file from a .torrent using Universal.torrent (monotorrent for UWP) https://github.com/zumicts/Universal.Torrent.

Here my code :

```
private async void Torrenttest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TorrentFunc tf = new TorrentFunc(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".torrent");
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        tf.DownloadTorrent(file.Path);
    }
```

and

```
class TorrentFunc
{  
  ClientEngine engine;
  StorageFolder savePath;

     // savePath is the directory where downloads will be stored
     public TorrentFunc(StorageFolder Path)
     {
         // Create a basic ClientEngine without changing any settings
         this.engine = new ClientEngine(new EngineSettings());
         this.savePath = Path;
     }

    public async void DownloadTorrent(string path)
    {
        Torrent torrent = await Task.Run(() => Torrent.Load(path));
      //  StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(savePath);
        TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, savePath, new TorrentSettings());
        engine.Register(manager);
        manager.Start();
    }


}
```

The error appears on line "Torrent torrent = await Task.Run(() => Torrent.Load(path));"

The file that i try to get is on my desktop and it's a simple .torrent file.

Thank you for read this and if you have any idea ;)

Comment: I don't see anywhere you've actually specified a path. Have you checked what is being passed to `DownloadTorrent`?

Comment: I select the file with the openpicker and i'm sure that the path is passed to downloadtorrrent cause the error details is {"Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\nicol\\Desktop\\test.torrent' is denied."}

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio/your application as administrator?

Comment: I try to run Visual Studio as Administrator and i get the same error.

Comment: While debugging the application? If you can run VS as administrator and the account you're currently on is 'nicol' then you should certainly have access to that file. Have you checked the permissions on the specific file and the Desktop folder? If you right-click and the torrent and go to Properties, is there an `Unlock` button at the bottom?

Comment: I just launch VS as administrator and load my project and then debbuging. I'm on the only session in the PC so 'nicol' session. some screen of properties : https://gyazo.com/eee466c911b6cfc490ee2c7de1fa52cb https://gyazo.com/74915af32bbc18e7185a2655650e5146

Comment: You should have access to that path.. have you checked again the exact error and path after running as administrator?

Comment: Yes i have : https://gyazo.com/8d2d209297c0c5e50aa6c124a8a362c8 as you can see VS as Administrator and same error. I have to specify that the project is a UWP project maybe it changes something ?

Comment: If you put the torrent file beside the .exe and simply use `@"test.torrent"` as the path, does that work?

Comment: When i put the file in the .exe folder i dont get the error anymore but i need to pick the file from somewhere else and the torrent dont seems to be download but maybe it's something else

Comment: I was just wondering if the code itself was working properly. It still seems like there is something strange with the permissions on that folder or file. You checked the permission on your specific account? In the screenshot it looks like you have "System" selected on the permission window.

Comment: i think my specific account is "nicolas vieira (nicolas......@gmail.com)" as you can see on the first screen, it's the account that i use to connect myself with Windows 10 and if yes i have the same permissions than system https://gyazo.com/666050965ff54b8028f29c1a59d3c22f

Comment: Can you perform any other operations on the file? `File.Copy`, something like that.